# Omitting “de” after “ça m'inquiète” seems wrong

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I wrote a sentence which my French teacher amended, although I am unsure if either of them are right...

I was trying to say "I am worried about all the environment problems which could destroy the planet", but omitting the 'de' from it makes it seem wrong.

Orginial:

> Ça m'inquiète de tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient détruire la terre...

Amended ('de' omitted):

> Ça m'inquiète tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient détruire la terre...

Is my teacher right? Or are we both wrong?

Comment: Teacher's right!

Answer (score 4):

Teachers are usually right.

> Ça m'inquiète de tous ...

is indeed incorrect.

> Ça m'inquiète, tous les ...

is correct, note the comma.

*S'inquiéter de* is possible when used this way :

> Je m'inquiète de tous ...

Comment: Tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient detruire la terre, ça m'inquiète (oralement)


Ca m'inquiète tous ces problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient detruire la terre (oralement)


Tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient detruire la terre m'inquiètent (écrit)


Je m'inquiète de tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient detruire la terre (écrit)

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be "Tous les problèmes environnementaux qui pourraient détruire la planète m'inquiètent".